# Drop and recreate table (locking)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update a large set of data into a SQL Server table which I use for caching and this happens about every 10 minutes.

I find that rather than using "Insert into ...tableName" that dropping the table and recreating it with "Select * INTO ...tableName" is a lot faster.

My question is though how do I lock the table i.e. prevent users querying the table whilst it is dropping or selecting into?

If I wrap it in a transaction does this work?

**Additional**
Just clarifying this further as I probably wasnt clear enough to start with.

I was originally using TRUNCATE and then INSERT INTO but this was taking around 8 - 10 seconds.  Which potentially can hold users up.

So what I wanted to do instead was to drop the table and then recreat the table with SELECT INTO which was very much faster.  However, I guess my question was what happens if someone queries the table after the DROP and before the SELECT INTO?  What happens in this instance?

Comment: Your query is a transaction. adding `begin tran...commit tran` adds no value here. Your drop table command will wait for the lock to be released. What are you really worried about here?

Comment: no drop table needs an exclusive lock and will not succeed ,if there is any conflicting lock

Comment: you may need use try partition switch instead of dropping entire table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option for you is to load your data into a table with temporary name, then quickly `DROP` your main table and `RENAME` the other.

Those are quite fast operations (atomic?), the unavailability should be minimal.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql

All you have to do is, for the very few users who will need to read the DB during the process, to show them a "please wait message" or similar, so that the user experience stays smooth (use a flag to track when the process starts/finish).

Comment: The poster is asking about SQL Server. MySQL docs might not get him what he needs.

Comment: Oh well, my bad. I am so used to read 'SQL Server' for pretty much anything that I forgot *something* was actually branded this way :-D But some ideas behind the answer might stay valid in SQLServer context... I hope.

Comment: @Fabien - I think your option regarding the temporary table is good.  If you modify your answer to be explicitly this I will mark it as correct.

Comment: I focused on this, and added recommendations for UX. :-) I added a MSSQL link to ALTER TABLE documentation, I am not into MSSQL so I hope it was the correct lead. According to other StackOverflow threads, the operation should be atomic.